# Make two rows equivalent based on differences between columns in R

Tags: r, select, filter, match, tidyverse

I have two dataframes of equal size:

```
df_1=data.frame(UA=c(1, 2, 3),plot1=c(100,100,100),plot2=c(100,0,0),plot3=c(100,100,0))

df_2=data.frame(UA=c(1, 2, 3),plot1=c(100,100,100),plot2=c(100,100,0),plot3=c(100,0,0))
```

What I'm trying to do is select only the cells that contain 100 in both `df_1` and `df_2` and in the **exact** place (i.e., the UA 1 example and plot1 only of both UA 2 and 3) and save in a list (because they will possibly have different sizes).

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use intersect for the element locations of 100 in each data frame:

```
intersect(which(df_1 == 100), which(df_2 == 100))
```

Edit: For row and column positions:

```
library(prodlim)

# Indices for data frame 1 and 2 for values = 100
indices_1 <- which(df_1 == 100, arr.ind = TRUE)
indices_2 <- which(df_2 == 100, arr.ind = TRUE)

# Rows where indices are matched between the two data frame indices
indices_rows <- na.omit(row.match(as.data.frame(indices_1), as.data.frame(indices_2)))

# Row-column indices where both data frames have values of 100
indices_2[indices_rows,]
```

Comment: It returns a vector of c(4,5,6,7,10), which I assume to be positions and 1,2,3 omitted, right? I dont understand why it returned 10 to me, though. And how can I use these values for filtering?

Comment: The 4, 5, 6, 7, and 10 will be the positions of the variables going down the columns left-to-right (e.g., positions 1, 2, 3 refer to UA = 1, 2, 3; positions 4, 5, 6 refer to plot1; and so on).

If you'd like row and column positions, see the edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem